# Slice of struct can't be plugged into slice of interface in golang

Tags: go

I have `Tag` struct and `TableAbstruct` interface like below example.

[Tag struct]

```
type Tag struct {
    Id   int    `db:"id"`
    Name string `db:"Name"`
}
func (tag Tag) Serialize() []string {
    ...
}
```

[TableAbstruct interface]

```
type TableAbstruct interface {
    Serialize() []string
}
```

`Xxx()` function returns `[]TableAbstruct`, but actual type is `[]Tag`. And below program will work well because `Tag` includes `TableAbstruct` interface.

```
func Xxx() []TableAbstruct {
    result := []TableAbstruct{}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        table_obj := Tag{}
        result = append(result, table_obj)
    }
    return result
}
```

But I want to write like below and I couldn't. I think the problem is TypeError. But I couldn't understand why the error has occurred.

```
func Xxx() []TableAbstruct {
    result := []Tag{}
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go does not have any fanciness around slices and types. Put simply, if you say you are going to return `[]TableAbstruct`, you have to return that exactly. So if you want to return a `[]Tag`, you have to create a slice of `[]TableAbstruct` and then go populate it manually:

```
func Xxx() []TableAbstruct {
  var returnValue []TableAbstruct
  for _, t := range result {
    returnValue = append(returnValue, t)
  }
  return returnValue
}
```